# Accessing several form options

Tags: javascript, html

How do I access several option values in a form, under two different select ids, with JavaScript?

Here's the code: (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianonline/9yL4rv6j/)

(HTML5)

Select your favorite fruit:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Click the button to return the value of the selected fruit.

Pick a product
Amount

```
        <label><strong>Amount:</strong></label>

        <select id="amount">
            <option selected>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>

<!-- text value here -->
<p id="include"></p>
<p id="include2"></p>
```

(JavaScript)

```
    function mySelect()

{

    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
    document.getElementById("include").innerHTML = p;

}

    function myAmount()

{

    var a = document.getElementById("amount").selectedIndex;
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[a].value;
    document.getElementById("include2").innerHTML = b;

}
```

Function mySelect() is able to pick the right option value and insert it in the first paragraph, however, the second function (myAmount()) is picking the same options as the first function, even though its id points to select id="amount". I need the second function to pick the options in select id="amount" and print it in p id="include2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `document.getElementsByTagName("option")`, which returns all option elements in the *document,* not all options for the current select. Which of course means your indexing is out.

But you can get the selected option's value in a given select element using the `.value` property of the select element itself:

```
function mySelect() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("include").innerHTML = x;
}
function myAmount() {
  document.getElementById("include2").innerHTML =
                                        document.getElementById("amount").value;
}
```